# func_two does not trigger in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript script code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/veZ5U/). When I execute my code as it is then it does not trigger `func_two` function. But when I change following code in `func_one`

```
    if (this.remove) {
        this.func_two;
    }
```

to this

```
    if (this.remove) {
        this.func_two();
    }
```

Then it does trigger second function. But I want to trigger it this way `this.func_one`. IS it possible to do it this way? How?

Comment: I really don't get "I want to do it this way" at all. Calling a function is done by writing `()` after it. If you want to do it another way, you have to find another programming language that agrees with you.

Comment: There is a way in backbone for example `this.collection.each(this.render, this);`. this.render is a function which is called without brackets.

Comment: @x4ph4r: No, the function is not called in this case. You are just passing a reference to the function to `.each` and `.each` calls it internally.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Alp I was trying to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163934/clicking-on-child-element-also-triggers-click-event-on-it-parent in different way but now it is not possible to do it this way, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `()` when you call a function, you can't just, out of nowhere, decide that you want it to work another way.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3246956/2182203) answer, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

`this.func_two;`
This statement return the function. It does not call the function.
 To call the function you have to add `()` at the end.
 or you have to do it like:
`f2=this.func_two;`
`f2();`