# Click event on child div trigger action despite click handler was set on parent using addEventListener (event bubbling was disabled))

Tags: javascript

I have three div boxes

The first div main has an id of `"main"` and contains two other boxes with id `"menu_header"` and `"menu_options"`

**this is my html**

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="menu_header">
  </div>
  <div id="menu_options">
  </div>
</div>
<span>Something here</span>
```

**this is my css**

```
#main{
  display:table-cell;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  border:solid purple;
}
#menu_header{
  position:relative;
  border:solid black;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  top:200px;
  height:100px;
 /* -moz-transition-property:bottom;
  -moz-transition-duration:2s;
  transition-property:top;
  transition-duration:1s;*/
}
#menu_options{
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0%;
  border:solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
/*#menu_header:active{
  top:100px;
}*/
```

(ignore css transition since it was commented out)

**this is my javascript**

```
function test(e){
 //if(e.target.id=="menu_options"){return};
 $('#menu_header').animate({top:'-10'},1000);
  //var t=document.getElementById('menu_header')
 // t.setAttribute('top','40px');
  t.style="position:relative;border:solid black;background:red;width:100px;top:60px;height:100px;"
}
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click',test,false)
```

**finally this is my lab rat jsfiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/ev7k688s/**

In this scenario, when I set a click event handler on my parent container with id `"main"` everything works perfectly except that whenever click on this parent's container child div with id `"menu_options"` it also triggers the handler

I found the link  below but somehow the `event.propogation()`  solution here seems not to work in my case.

[clicking on child element also triggers click event on it parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163934/clicking-on-child-element-also-triggers-click-event-on-it-parent)

One nasty hack, to prevent the any actions from executing if the child div capture the event was

```
if(e.target.id=="menu_header"){return};
```

THe above I commented out in my javascript code.

**Question:**
why is the child div with id `"menu_options"` capturing the event from the parent container with id `"main"` despite me setting `false` on `add EventListener` to prevent event bubbling.?

Comment: It's `event.stopPropagation()`, not `event.propagation()`. Setting `false` with `addEventListener()` does not disable bubbling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The cause***

Passing `false` to `.addEventListener()` does not disable bubbling. It simply makes  it so that the event fires during the bubbling phase instead of the capturing phase.

When an event takes place, it starts at the root of the DOM and enters the "capturing" phase. This means that the event works its way from the `document` to the `event.target`, firing any "capturing" handlers it finds along the way.

Once it reaches the `event.target`, it reverses course, and traverses back up to the `document`, invoking any "bubbling" handlers it finds.

So because you passed `false` as the third  argument, the handler will be invoked during that last "bubbling" phase.

So you see, this does not do anything to prevent nested elements from invoking the handler.

---

***The solution***

If you *only* want to invoke the handler when clicking on the actual element, and none of its children, simply halt the handler if `this` does not equal `e.target`.

```
function test(e){
   if (this != e.target)
      return;

   $('#menu_header').animate({top:'-10'},1000);
   var t=document.getElementById('menu_header')
   t.setAttribute('top','40px');
   t.style="position:relative;border:solid black;background:red;width:100px;top:60px;height:100px;"
}
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click',test,false)
```

Comment: This is very understandable!..I tried using if "(this != e.target); return"... but nothing happens...any suggestions?

Comment: I replace "this != e.target" with " document.getElementById('menu_options') != e.target"...sticking to my question which is asking for an explanation of  why I am encountering this issue..I will accept this answer...:D

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict event bubbling by 2 scenario.
1. Put Click event on each DOM object, means child to parent and put event.stropPropagation().
2. Identify the DOM object using e.target.id and return "false".[We are using this]

Code below

```
<script>
        function test(e) {
            if (e.target.id == "menu_header") { return }
            else if (e.target.id == "menu_options") { return }
            $('#menu_header').animate({ top: '-10' }, 1000);
            var t = document.getElementById('menu_header')
            t.setAttribute('top','40px');
            t.style = "position:relative;border:solid black;background:red;width:100px;top:60px;height:100px;"
        }
         window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', test, false);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop propagation in the child element. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/ev7k688s/3/).

```
function test(){
 $('#menu_header').animate({top:'10'},1000);
  //var t=document.getElementById('menu_header')
 // t.setAttribute('top','40px');
  //t.style="position:relative;border:solid black;background:red;width:100px;top:60px;height:100px;"
}

function stopPropagation(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click',test,false);

document.getElementById('menu_header').addEventListener('click',stopPropagation,false);
```

Comment: This is really smart...and ridiculously beautiful!

Comment: Thanks, also if this was the solution that you were looking for, kindly mark it as accepted answer.